# pandas to sql server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I got following code. The problem is I could read data use panda.read_sql, but I could not use the DataFrame.to_sql() function.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 15)
pd.set_option('precision', 4)

conn = pyodbc.connect(r"Driver={SQL Server};Server=dev;Database=test1")

data = pd.read_sql_query(
    """
SELECT *
FROM   sys.tables
    """
    , con = conn)

print data
data.to_sql('test', con = conn)
```

the error is the following:

> Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE
>   type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208)
>   (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Is there a way to get around?

Comment: Does `test` table exist in database in `dbo` schema? If not use the [if_exists](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) argument to replace/append. The default is fail.

Comment: @Parfait I used replace option, and it is giving the same error.

Comment: pandas `to_sql` does not support MS SQL Server connection directly, you need to use sqlalchemy to connect as shown in the answer of @Parfait

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Consider creating a sqlalchemy [MSSQL engine](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html) and use that in pandas `to_sql()` con argument:

```
import sqlalchemy

...
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
               "mssql+pyodbc://user:pwd@server/database",
               echo=False)

data.to_sql('test', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: If there's more than one schema per DB, the table is identified by `[MySchemaName].[MyTableName]`. The schema can be passed as a parameter to to_sql like: `my_dataframe.to_sql(name='MyTableName', con=engine, if_exists='replace', schema='MySchemaName')`, if I was not passing the schema then it didn't work for me. Also the connection string that worked for me has this format: `"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;SERVER={0};PORT=1433;DATABASE={1};UID={2};PWD={3};TDS_Version=8.0;".format(server, database, user, password)))`

Comment: @TPPZ ... thank you for your note which future readers will appreciate.

Comment: @TPPZ I spent almost an hour trying to resolve issues writing dataframe to MSSQL with pandas's `to_sql` via `sqlalchemy`, and your comment is the ONLY ONE that worked with all the info that I needed. Thanks very much for finally saving my evening!