# Python connect to SQL Server - PYODBC - SQLAlchemy: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to establish a connection to SQL Server so I can upload my df to a table (using `.to_sql()`) and run a query later on with this new table. My issue is that when trying to establish a connection to SQL Server (work database is on SQL Server ) I get the same error message when trying a couple of different methods.

```
    #Method 1
    TR_info = pd.read_excel(TR_path, sheet_name = 'TR information', skiprows = 3)

    cnxn_str = (r"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                r"Server=server_name;"
                r"Database=ALDB;"
                r"Trusted_Connection=yes;") 
    
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)

    TR_info.to_sql(name='tr_info', schema='RF1', con = cnxn, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

```
    #Method 2
    TR_info = pd.read_excel(TR_path, sheet_name = 'TR information', skiprows = 3)

    import sqlalchemy as sal

    engine = sal.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://server_name/ALDB?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0?Trusted_Connection=yes')

    conn = engine.connect()

    TR_info.to_sql(name='tr_info', schema='RF1', con = conn, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

**Both methods give me the following error message.**

> (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)

Finally, I have also confirmed I have SQL Native client 11.0 setup in my ODBC Data Source Administrator, so it is not that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas to sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487153/pandas-to-sql-server)

Comment: Nope, I also had seen that and used it for my second method but still get the same error message. Unless you can see any differences between my method and the one you linked which I have missed? Note mine is a trusted connection and that example is not, but I think I have formatted it correctly..

Comment: You are calling `engine.connect()`. In the example the engine object is given to `to_sql`

Comment: Also have a look in the first comment with a different format for the connection string

Comment: The error message in the title is very different from the error message in the question itself. I'm confused.

Comment: Apologies, error message was incorrect, updated now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a different driver, but maybe try the following syntax using **quote_plus**:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

    SQL_SERVER_NAME = ''
    SQL_DB_NAME = ''
    SQL_USER = ''
    SQL_PW = ''

    odbc_connection_string = f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};Server=tcp:{SQL_SERVER_NAME}.database.windows.net,1433;Database={SQL_DB_NAME};Uid={SQL_USER}@{SQL_SERVER_NAME};Pwd={SQL_PW};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={quote_plus(odbc_connection_string)}"
```